# How closure work in acceleo?

Tags: acceleo

I have a element with a child element name nextElement

```
a.nextElement is b
b.nextElement is c
c.nextElement is d
```

When I do a request a->closure(a.nextElement) I expect to get a set with b, c and d but I only get b. What I am not understanding or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like?:

```
a -> closure(child:Element | true)
```

true is an expression. You can specify there any condition you need.

I saw it [here](http://modeling-languages.com/closure-operation-added-to-ocl/)

Even though I'm not sure that `closure` is included in Acceleo API (I repeat, not sure). I tried to use `closure` function but the IDE didn't suggested it to me.

In my project, I made this generic query by my own:

```
[query public descendants(aElement : Node): 
    Set(Node) =  if (aElement.oclIsTypeOf(Element)) then
                        Set{aElement} -> union (aElement.oclAsType(Element).children 
                            -> collect (n : Node | descendants(n)) -> asSet() )  
                    else
                        Set{aElement}
                    endif 
    /]
```

I hope this would help !!!

Comment: Actually, the Acceleo compiler/engine are able to deal with closure, but the IDE is not (not sure why). In the example provided by Martin, the way the deal with reccursive call could be `a->closure(child : Element | child.nextElement)` or, for short, `a->closure(nextElement)` . If the expression originally provided by Martin was not working, it is because of the variable binding (`a` is not free anymore). Var `a` is binded to an instance durig execution. Reusing it in the closure does not invalidate this binding so the expression `a->nextElement` always should resolve to the same result.